# IE automation through Excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

The problem that I'm having is quite simple. I'm opening a webpage, looking for the input box where I type some text and then hit a Search button. Once the new webpage is uploaded I gather all the info I need. My problem is in the time spent uploading the webpage. My gathering code doesn't work because the new webpage is still not loaded. I have the following code to wait for that:

```
Do While ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
            DoEvents
 Loop
```

where ie was set like this

```
Set ie = New InternetExplorer
```

Is there another code except the `application.wait` that I can use to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I've run into similar issues when attempting the same. The issue is that the ready state on the IE object can't always be trusted, or at the very least, it's not signaling what you think. For example it will let you know when each frame is ready, not the whole page. So if you don't actually need to see the web browser control, and you only care about sending and receiving data. My suggestion is to not bother rending the page in a web browser object, instead just send and receive data using a WinHttpRequest.

Tools>References>Microsoft WinHTTP Services

Using this, you can send and receive the HTML data directly. If your page uses URL parameters, you send a "GET" then parse the reply. Otherwise you will have to send a "PUT" and send the edited HTML (Basically take the blank form page you begin with and set all the values). When first using, it can be a bit tricky to get the formatting correct depending on the complexity of the page you are trying to automate. Find a good web dugging tool (such as Fiddler) so that you can see the HTML being sent to your target page.